# Angular Error : Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'AbstractControl'

Tags: javascript, angular, mean

I got an error when setting the default value of my FormControl, but it returns an error like this :

> error TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'AbstractControl'

This is my .ts file :

```
  profileForm  = new FormGroup({ 
    username   : new FormControl().setValue("a"),
    firstname  : new FormControl().setValue("a"),
    lastname   : new FormControl().setValue("a"),
    email      : new FormControl().setValue("a"),
    password   : new FormControl().setValue("a"),
  });
```

Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use form builder:

```
profileForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
        this.profileForm  = this._formBuilder.group({
            username: [{ value: 'a' }],
            ...
          }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`FormControl.setValue()` returns a `void` - which means it returns nothing.

You're effectively trying to create an object with the following signature:

```
{
  username: void,
  firstname: void,
  ...
}
```

Which is both meaningless and invalid for constructing a `FormGroup`. FormGroup expects an object with the following signature in its constructor:

```
{
  [key: string]: FormControl
}
```

So something more like:

```
{
  username: new FormControl(),
  firstname: new FormControl(),
  ...
}
```

If you want to access the form controls programmatically, you could do this:

```
const formControls = {
  username: new FormControl('a'),
  firstname: new FormControl('a'),
  ...
};

// or this
formControls.username.setValue('a');
formControls.firstname.setValue('a');
// ... etc

profileForm = new FormGroup({
  username: formControls.username,
  firstname: formControls.firstname,
  ...
});
```

Comment: you can also set the default value for the `FormControl` by passing the value as first parameter. Take a look over FormControl class documentation https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl.

`username   : new FormControl("a"),`

Comment: @MohamedMounir Thanks for that. I initially just refactored the code as was, but your suggestion is of course a better way